# Error: Could not resolve 'home' from state ''...Why?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an application as a homework with Angular's ui-route.
It's like an agenda, where users will store contacts grouped by categories and more...It's contacts view would be similar to this one, plaxo.[image]

I'm using Angular with ui-router and nodejs.

### The views:

- Home
- Contacts
- Reminders

Contacts will have three different columns or divs inside:

- Categories (List of categories that contacts belong to)
- Contacts (List of contacts)
- Contact information (about a particular contact)

Contact information will have change it's form depending of what type of operation the user want to do. Contact information:

- Contact info display (read only contact information)
- Contact info modify (update contact information)
- New contact (insert contact information, could be similar to modifying)

### The error

When i click on the navbar ui-sref links:

> Error: Could not resolve 'home' from state ''

```js
angular.module("appAgenda", ['ui.router'])

 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('index.home');

 $stateProvider
  .state("index",{
   url: "",
   templateUrl: "index",
   abstract: true,
  })
  .state("index.home", {
   url: "home",
   templateUrl: "index-home",
  })
  .state("index.contacts", {
   url: "contacts",
   templateUrl: "index-contacts",
   abstract: true
  })
  .state("index.contacts.info", {
   url: "contactsInfo",
   templateUrl: "index-contacts-info"
  })
  .state("index.contacts.edit", {
   url: "contactsEdit",
   templateUrl: "index-contacts-edit"
  })
  .state("index.contacts.new", {
   url: "contactsEdit", //uses the same template as contactsEdit
   templateUrl: "index-contacts-new"
  })
  .state('index.reminders', {
   url: "/reminders",
   templateUrl: "index-reminders"
  }); 
 })
;
```

```css
module.exports = function(express, app){
    app.set('views', __dirname + "/client/views/");
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.render("index");
    });
    app.get("/home", function(req, res){
     res.render("index-home");
    });
    app.get("/contacts", function(req, res){
        res.render("index-contacts");
    });
    app.get("/contactsInfo", function(req, res){
        res.render("index-contacts-info");
    });
    app.get("/contactsEdit", function(req, res){
        res.render("index-contacts-edit");
    });
    app.get("/contactsEdit", function(req, res){
        res.render("index-contacts-new");
    });
    app.get("/reminders", function(req, res){
        res.render("index-reminders");
    });

    
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));    
};
```

```html
doctype html
html(lang="es")
head
 meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
 //bootstrap
 link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous")
 link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous")
 //style.js
 link(rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css")


body(ng-app="appAgenda")
 nav.navbar.navbar-inverted.navbar-fixed-top
  div.container
   ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li(ui-sref="home") Inicio
    li(ui-sref="contacts") Contactos
    li(ui-sref="reminders") Recordatorios
    li(ui-sref="logout") Logout
 div(ui-view)
 
 //jquery
 script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js")
 script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js")
 //font-awesome
 link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")
 //angular.js
 script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js")
 script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js")
 script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js")
 script(src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/marklagendijk/ui-router.stateHelper/master/statehelper.min.js")
 script(src="../js/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.min.js")
 script(src="../js/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.tpls.min.js")
 //angular.src
 script(src="../js/app.js")
 script(src="../js/config.js")
 script(src="../js/routes.js")
 script(src="../js/services.js")
 script(src="../js/filters.js")
 script(src="../js/controllers.js")
```

**It would be nice to hear some critics or other different approaches to this route-nesting code that could be useful.**

Comment: You have no "home" state. You do have an "index.home" state

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('index.home'); is better? new at this

Comment: No, you need to define a "home" state.`.state("home", {
   url: "/home",
   templateUrl: "whatever the URL",
  })`  or change `(ui-sref="home")` to `(ui-sref="index.home")`